# Fables character identification

Tags: character-identification, vertigo-comics, fables-comics

Who is the space-looking character in this Fables panel from the last volume? Has he been shown or mentioned in earlier chapters?

> [image]
>
>  It appears that he and Winter are a couple

Comment: I don't think so, no. IIRC, all we really know of Winter between the end of the story and the reunion scene is that Hel is somehow descended from her.

Comment: "*One of the family members seen, the goddess Hel, is said to be descended from Winter, though the exact line of descent is not know. Winter, herself, is seen accompanied by an unknown entity by her side.*" - https://fables.fandom.com/wiki/Winter_Wolf_(Comic_Series)